# Error: failed to read row 0, column -1. weired

Tags: android

What is wrong here that is causing Exception to occur?? I dont find any issue here. Can anyone look into this:

```
private Cursor getAllPhoneNumbersForNamesLike(String str){
    Cursor tempContact=null;
    tempContact=this.getContentResolver().query(uriContact,null,"display_name like ?",new String[]{tokenLike+"%"},null);
    if(tempContact!=null && tempContact.getCount()>0){
        try{
            tempContact.moveToFirst();
            Toast.makeText(this,tempContact.getString(tempContact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Inside getAllPhoneNumbersForNamesLike catch: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }
        return this.getContentResolver().query(uriSmsRead,null,inClause,null,null);
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: private Uri uriContact=ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

Comment: Give us the error and stack trace.

Comment: String tokenLike="SJ"

Comment: 05-09 04:15:42.888: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3668): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
05-09 04:15:42.888: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3668):   in android.view.ViewRootImpl@40d81208
05-09 04:15:42.888: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3668):   0: sent at 22940735000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, 
scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22940735, downTime=22940633, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
05-09 04:15:45.408: E/CursorWindow(3668): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 29 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stacktrace

```
05-09 04:15:42.888: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3668): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down. 
05-09 04:15:42.888: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3668): in android.view.ViewRootImpl@40d81208 
05-09 04:15:42.888: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3668): 0: sent at 22940735000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22940735, downTime=22940633, deviceId=0, source=0x101 } 
05-09 04:15:45.408: E/CursorWindow(3668): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 29 columns
```

You need to look into your

```
tempContact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
```

Sounds like of your 29 Columns, non matches the above

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or ***-1 if the column doesn't exist***. If you expect the column to exist use getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead, which will make the error more clear.

---

**Edit**

try this:

```
getColumnIndexOrThrow((ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
```

Then paste your new `LogCat` in your question.

Comment: but ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER is the proper column name of ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI

Comment: There's no leading or trailing spaces? Case differences? Any small little thing that could be different?

Comment: I understand Asok.. this is as it is

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I got the reason Asok.. I need to use ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI; URI instead... Anyways.. Thanks for your help and support

Comment: Great, well hope that fully resolves your issue. Best of luck.